# script only execute first command

Tags: batch-file, glassfish

I would like to create a script to configure my domain in glassfish but I'm missing something. This is my script:

script.bat
asadmin set configs.config.server-config.system-property.HTTP_LISTENER_PORT.value=10080
asadmin set configs.config.server-config.system-property.HTTP_SSL_LISTENER_PORT.value=10443

(script.bat is in the same folder as asadmin.bat)

the problem is that when I execute it, only the first command is executed.. what am I missing?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set `CALL` before each bat you execute with your script...